# Let $(X_n)_{n \in N}$ be a Markov chain with the set of states $I=\{ 0,1,2,3\}$ and with given transition matrix.$P\{ X_5=1, X_3=1, X_2=3| X_1 = 2\}$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random

Let $(X_n)_{n \in N}$ be a Markov chain with the set of states $I=\{ 0,1,2,3\}$ and with the given transition matrix:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
    0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The probability $P\{ X_5=1, X_3=1, X_2=3| X_1 = 2\}$ is being questioned.

I have not done this type of question. There are a couple like this. I believe this might not be too dificult to understand, but I just do not know how to go about solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First applying Bayes theorem and then the Markovian property:
$$P[X_5=1,X_3=1,X_2=3|X_1=2]
= P[X_5=1,X_3=1|X_2=3,X_1=2] \cdot P[X_2=3|X_1=2]
= P[X_5=1,X_3=1|X_2=3] \cdot P[X_2=3|X_1=2] $$
Repeating this then gives
$$P[X_5=1,X_3=1,X_2=3|X_1=2] = P[X_5=1|X_3=1]\cdot P[X_3=1|X_2=3]\cdot P[X_2=3|X_1=2]$$

In fact the transition matrix doesn’t change, so we can rewrite this as
$$P[X_5=1,X_3=1,X_2=3|X_1=2] = P[X_{n+2}=1|X_n=1]\cdot P[X_{n+1}=1|X_n=3]\cdot P[X_{n+1}=3|X_n=2]$$

The $i,j$th element of the state transition matrix represents the probability of a transition to state $j$ from state $i$. Therefore we can write
$$\left(P\right)_{i,j} = P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)$$
In fact, the $i,j$th element of the $k$th power of the state matrix gives the probability of a transition from $i$ to $j$ at the $k$th transition.
$$\left(P^k\right)_{i,j} = P(X_{n+k}=j|X_n=i)$$
Hence you should compute the transition matrix squared and then read off the coefficients:
$$P[X_5=1,X_3=1,X_2=3|X_1=2]
= \left(P^2\right)_{1,1} \left(P\right)_{3,1} \left(P\right)_{2,3} $$

Comment: Is it a problem if you could give me the Bayes thereom on which you concluded the first equality, and how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: I actually just used the definition of the conditional probability $P[A|B]$ where $$P[A,B]=P[A|B]P[B].$$Bayes’ theorem relates the conditional probabilities as $$P[A,B]=P[A|B]P[B]=P[B|A]P[A]$$ but as I said we are only using the first equality